# How to set text colour in array if you are using android adapter?

Tags: java, android

I want to override the text colour in the android adapter, how can I do that. The values of the string will be loaded from backend service.

Plz help me out.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.report_symptomlv);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mSymptoms);


        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

//--------------
alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    mName = input.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
//----I need to make this text as Orange----
                    Geocoder mGeoCoder = new Geocoder(favorite.this, Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

**-** I believe a Code is better than thousand Words, but still  some guys need more than that, and so i would like to explain it....

**-** You will need to use `getView()` method that will be in used to defining the **attributes** of the inflated views in the `ListView`.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ReferralsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,numList){

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,20);
                ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return v;
            }

        };
```

Comment: and where is the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom Listview. You will have more flexibility in inflating the views and styling them. For custom listview have a look at this link. http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1.